# How to start Flask in DEBUG mode with supervisord in Docker dev context?

Tags: debugging, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm developing an app and try to run a `flask` instance in `DEBUG` mode through `supervisord` in a [`Docker` environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#/different-environments).

### Supervisord config

I'm using `supervisord` to start both my *nginx* and *flask* instances.

#### *flask.conf*

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:flask]
command=gunicorn views:app -b localhost:5000 -w 2
directory=/daemon/api
```

#### *nginx.conf*

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log

[program:nginx]
command=nginx
```

### Docker config

#### *docker-compose.override.yml*

```
version: '2'

services:
  backend:
     …
  daemon:
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=/daemon/api/views.py
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
    volumes:
      - ./daemon/api:/daemon/api
    command: supervisord
  frontend:
    …
```

#### Question

Despite having set the [`FLASK_DEBUG=1`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/server/#server) as an environment variable in my *docker-compose.override.yml*, `flask` isn't running in debug mode.

What do I need to change for it to run in debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

#### */etc/supervisor/conf.d/dev.conf*

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/flask-dev.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

#### */etc/supervisor/conf.d/flask-dev.conf*

Run the development server as a module with the new method [`python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#old-version-of-flask) (otherwise didn't work behind `nginx`)

```
[program:dev]
command=python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
directory=/daemon/api
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/flask.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
```

#### *docker-compose.override.yml*

Run a special command to start `supervisord` with the `dev.conf` when on development environment and also setup `FLASK_DEBUG=1`:

```
…
daemon:
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=/daemon/api/views.py
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
    volumes:
      - ./daemon/api:/daemon/api
    command: supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/dev.conf
…
```

#### *nginx.conf*

From the example in *Standalone WSGI Containers [Proxy Setups section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups)*, I noticed **trailing slashes**, so add them to my `location` and `proxy_pass` directives.

```
location /daemon/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```